# Como puedo guardar campos solicitados al inicio de sesión de Facebook?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook

Estoy utilizando el SDK de facebook para hacer un inicio de sesión y estoy incluyéndolo en ruby on rails, el ejemplo que estoy utilizando es uno básico que utiliza callbacks agrade seria si pudieran decirme si se puede guardar la información como referencia en un DB ya que se hará para un aparatado de anuncios clasificados, este es el código que estoy utilizando.

html:

```
<a href="#" id="login" class="btn btn-primary">Iniciar sesión</a>

    <script>
        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

y este es el js:

```
$(function() {

    var app_id = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    var scopes = 'email, user_friends, user_online_presence';

    var btn_login = '<a href="#" id="login" class="btn btn-primary">Iniciar sesión</a>';

    var div_session = "<div id='facebook-session'>"+
                      "<strong></strong>"+
                      "<img>"+
                      "<a href='#' id='logout' class='btn btn-danger'>Cerrar sesión</a>"+
                      "</div>";

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        FB.init({
            appId      : app_id,
            status     : true,
            cookie     : true, 
            xfbml      : true, 
            version    : 'v2.1'
        });


        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response, function() {});
        });
    };

    var statusChangeCallback = function(response, callback) {
        console.log(response);

        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            getFacebookData();
        } else {
            callback(false);
        }
    }

    var checkLoginState = function(callback) {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            callback(response);
        });
    }

    var getFacebookData =  function() {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            $('#login').after(div_session);
            $('#login').remove();
            $('#facebook-session strong').text("Bienvenido: "+response.name);
            $('#facebook-session img').attr('src','http://graph.facebook.com/'+response.id+'/picture?type=large');
        });
    }

    var facebookLogin = function() {
        checkLoginState(function(data) {
            if (data.status !== 'connected') {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.status === 'connected')
                        getFacebookData();
                }, {scope: scopes});
            }
        })
    }

    var facebookLogout = function() {
        checkLoginState(function(data) {
            if (data.status === 'connected') {
                FB.logout(function(response) {
                    $('#facebook-session').before(btn_login);
                    $('#facebook-session').remove();
                })
            }
        })

    }

    $(document).on('click', '#login', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        facebookLogin();
    })

    $(document).on('click', '#logout', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (confirm("¿Está seguro?"))
            facebookLogout();
        else 
            return false;
    })
})
```

estaré agradecido si me pudieran decir si esto me pudieran dar uno ejemplos de como guardar la información en una DB,p para hacer referencias futuras.